# React Weather simple app - works in codesandbox but not VSCode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, weather, codesandbox

I am making a beginner React weather app with Geolocation. Here is the code. The main code is in **App.js**. **Daily** and **Hourly** are for displaying only.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Hourly from "./Components/Hourly";
import Daily from "./Components/Daily";

const App = () => {
    const [currentWeatherOne, setCurrentWeatherOne] = useState({});
    const [currentWeatherTwo, setCurrentWeatherTwo] = useState({});
    const [currentWeatherThree, setCurrentWeatherThree] = useState({});
    const [currentWeatherFour, setCurrentWeatherFour] = useState({});
    const [currentWeatherFive, setCurrentWeatherFive] = useState({});
    const [lat, setLat] = useState();
    const [long, setLong] = useState();
    const [today, setToday] = useState();
    const [tomorrow1, setTomorrow1] = useState({});
    const [tomorrow2, setTomorrow2] = useState({});
    const [refreshText, setRefreshText] = useState();

    const getPosition = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve);
        });
    };

    const getWeather = async (lat, long) => {
        let a = await fetch(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=dcadf332823cddfb979926a1414274e8&units=metric`
        );
        let b = await a.json();
        console.log(b);
        setCurrentWeatherOne(b.list[1]);
        setCurrentWeatherTwo(b.list[2]);
        setCurrentWeatherThree(b.list[3]);
        setCurrentWeatherFour(b.list[4]);
        setCurrentWeatherFive(b.list[5]);
        setToday(b.list[0]);
        setTomorrow1(b.list[11]);
        setTomorrow2(b.list[19]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getPosition().then(data => {
            setLat(data.coords.latitude);
            setLong(data.coords.longitude);
            getWeather(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);
        });
    }, []);

    // console.log(currentWeatherOne, currentWeatherThree, currentWeatherFive);

    const refresh = () => {
        getWeather(lat, long);
        let hours = String(new Date().getHours());
        let minutes = String(new Date().getMinutes());
        let seconds = String(new Date().getSeconds());
        setRefreshText(
            `Updated as of: ${hours}:${minutes.length < 2 ? "0" : ""}${minutes}:${
            seconds.length < 2 ? "0" : ""
            }${seconds}`
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header>Geolocation weather</header>
            <button onClick={refresh}>Refresh</button>
            <br />
            {refreshText}
            <hr />
            <h3>Hourly</h3>
            <div className="container-2">
                <Hourly
                    icon={currentWeatherOne.weather[0].icon}
                    time={currentWeatherOne.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={currentWeatherOne.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={currentWeatherOne.main.temp_max}
                    description={currentWeatherOne.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={currentWeatherOne.main.humidity}
                />
                <Hourly
                    icon={currentWeatherTwo.weather[0].icon}
                    time={currentWeatherTwo.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={currentWeatherTwo.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={currentWeatherTwo.main.temp_max}
                    description={currentWeatherTwo.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={currentWeatherTwo.main.humidity}
                />
                <Hourly
                    icon={currentWeatherThree.weather[0].icon}
                    time={currentWeatherThree.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={currentWeatherThree.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={currentWeatherThree.main.temp_max}
                    description={currentWeatherThree.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={currentWeatherThree.main.humidity}
                />
                <Hourly
                    icon={currentWeatherFour.weather[0].icon}
                    time={currentWeatherFour.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={currentWeatherFour.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={currentWeatherFour.main.temp_max}
                    description={currentWeatherFour.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={currentWeatherFour.main.humidity}
                />
                <Hourly
                    icon={currentWeatherFive.weather[0].icon}
                    time={currentWeatherFive.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={currentWeatherFive.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={currentWeatherFive.main.temp_max}
                    description={currentWeatherFive.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={currentWeatherFive.main.humidity}
                />
            </div>
            <h3>Daily</h3>
            <div className="container-1">
                <Daily
                    icon={today.weather[0].icon}
                    time={today.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={today.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={today.main.temp_max}
                    description={today.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={today.main.humidity}
                />
                <Daily
                    icon={tomorrow1.weather[0].icon}
                    time={tomorrow1.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={tomorrow1.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={tomorrow1.main.temp_max}
                    description={tomorrow1.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={tomorrow1.main.humidity}
                />
                <Daily
                    icon={tomorrow2.weather[0].icon}
                    time={tomorrow2.dt_txt}
                    minTemp={tomorrow2.main.temp_min}
                    maxTemp={tomorrow2.main.temp_max}
                    description={tomorrow2.weather[0].description}
                    humidity={tomorrow2.main.humidity}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**Daily**

```
import React from "react";

const Daily = ({ icon, time, minTemp, maxTemp, description, humidity }) => {
  let timeToShow = time.split(" ")[0];
  let one = timeToShow.split("-")[0];
  let two = timeToShow.split("-")[1];
  let three = timeToShow.split("-")[2];

  maxTemp = Math.floor(maxTemp);
  minTemp = Math.floor(minTemp);
  description = description
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => {
      return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    })
    .join(" ");

  return (
    <div className="weather">
      <div>
        {three}-{two}-{one}
      </div>
      <img
        src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon}.png`}
        alt="weather icon"
      />
      <div>
        <div>
          <span className="temp">{maxTemp}</span>
          <span>{minTemp}</span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>{description}</div>
        <br />
        {humidity}% humidity
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Daily;
```

**Hourly**

```
import React from "react";

const Hourly = ({ description, humidity, time, icon, minTemp, maxTemp }) => {
  let timeToShow = time.split(" ")[1];
  let first = timeToShow.split(":")[0];
  let second = timeToShow.split(":")[1];
  maxTemp = Math.floor(maxTemp);
  minTemp = Math.floor(minTemp);
  description = description
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => {
      return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    })
    .join(" ");

  return (
    <div className="weather">
      <div>
        {first}:{second}
      </div>
      <img
        src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${icon}.png`}
        alt="weather icon"
      />
      <div>
        <div>
          <span className="temp">{maxTemp}</span>
          <span>{minTemp}</span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>{description}</div>
        <br />
        {humidity}% humidity
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hourly;
```

On codesandbox, sometimes it does not work, so what I have to do is comment all the **Daily** and **Hourly** components, wait 2 seconds for codesandbox to re-load, and uncomment them and generally it will work.

Not so on VSCode. It will say that **currentWeatherOne.weather is undefined** which means **currentWeatherOne** tries to access the information that is not there yet. I don't understand, isn't this the whole point of using a promise? Using async, await etc? So that it waits for the result to be given back, **then** display it? Whatever the reason, why does it work on codesandbox and not VSCode?

Would really love to get feedback and help. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentWeatherOne is set to just empty object `{}` initially and you are trying to access `currentWeatherOne.weather[0].icon` in the return section. since `weather` is not available in `currentWeatherOne` yet, you are getting this error.

UseEffect is called after the first render so your `getWeather` to fetch the weather info is called after the initial render. Until that time, `currentWeatherOne` is just empty object.

Have fixed the issue here - https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wood-b4kuh

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are exactly correct @Arpitha. However, how come this works ok in codesandbox? And also, would you be able to tell me the solution to this?

Comment: I created a codesanbox for the same and it doesn't seem to work - https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wood-b4kuh

Comment: yes, like I mentioned, you will have to comment all the **Daily** and **Hourly** components inside **App**, wait 3-4 seconds for codesandbox to re-load, then uncomment them.

Comment: Even after doing the steps that u have mentioned, i keep getting the same error.

Comment: Hmmm... that is weird. I also get errors, but as I said, the moment I comment all of those components, wait 4-5 seconds, and un-comment, I normally get it working. Anyway, do you know of any solution to this?

Comment: Have fixed the issue here - https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wood-b4kuh

Comment: Yes, I noticed you used the technique like **{currentWeatherOne && (<Component />)}**

What does it mean? I tried doing that to mine but does not work

Comment: It means, only if currentWeatherOne is available/truthy, <Component /> will be rendered. For this to work, set `currentWeatherOne` to empty initially like this - `const [currentWeatherOne, setCurrentWeatherOne] = useState();`

Comment: Thanks Arpitha. I understand that the first part means **if currentWeatherOne has data inside it** but what does the second part mean? Isn't it just simply rendering the **Component** ? I thought that when you use &&, the second part should **also** be a conditional?

Comment: with &&, second part will not be evaluated if the first part is falsy. So it will not evaluate <Component /> part unless value of currentWeatherOne is truthy.

Comment: Ah I see....all this time I thought that with  &&, both sides have to be a conditional. Now I understand. Thank you very much for your help.